# VBA Do Until loop sometimes fails

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing some pretty basic Excel VBA Macros to do with splitting and merging large workbooks on their worksheets. I've got it mostly ironed out, but I have a failure occuring intermittently (about 1 time in 10) that I can't seem to reliably reproduce, let alone fix.

There are 205 or so single-sheeted workbooks in the folder I'm interested in, and the macro uses Dir() to cycle through them, ending when it reaches an empty filename. Except sometimes it doesn't.

It will occasionally just stop at a random point of going through these files. I've seen it happen between 60-190 imports, and it just stops the execution at that point with no error or warning. The rest of the code after the Do Until Loop doesn't get executed.

Has anyone run across something similar? Is it a memory issue within excel? I'm losing my mind here. Adding a timer to the loop to slow it down has not helped. There are no open files within the folder I'm merging from. Suppressing the alerts that popup during the merging processes is not the issue.

Here's the code for the loop:

```
    strFilename = Dir(myPath & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)

    If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Do Until strFilename = ""
        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=myPath & "\" & strFilename, UpdateLinks:=False)
        Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)
        wsSrc.Copy after:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)
        wbSrc.Close False
        strFilename = Dir()
    Loop
```

Comment: Do any of the workbooks you are opening have code in and are you using a shortcut key involving the shift key to run this macro?

Comment: Does an error appear or does the code just stop running at some point without any error window?

Comment: I'll check to be 100% on the macro shortcuts (It's not my data or sheets, I just have to manipulate them) but I'm pretty confident it's all plaintext and no macros @Rory

EDIT: can confirm no macros at all in any of the sheets.

Comment: No error occurs. The process just stops executing at various points in the loop (sometimes the workbook it's up to is open, sometimes not) @smagnan

Comment: Have you tried change the "Do Until" Condition to 'Len(strFilename) = 0' as well? Maybe somethings wrong with the comparison with "".

Comment: @oerl I'll give that a shot now, but I don't think so due to the random nature of where it halts. Will be a little while until I'm able to confirm due to the long runtime and lowish break chance.

Comment: Maybe you can try to add an error handler if you do not have one (`On error goto XXX ... XXX:`) A dirty way to find what can cause the error could be to add a `Debug.print <different text from each instruction>` after each instruction to see which instruction causes the error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Massive thanks to Rory's comment for the shift-key hint (and all the other help too, of course). There were no macros running that were using the Shift key but occasionally as I alt-tabbed out, I'd use alt-shift-tab or some other combination using shift and break it due to Excel's "No shift when opening" security rule.

The documentation on the [microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555263) page has a resolution for this issue, involving detecting when the shift key is held and running another loop inside the Do Until that prevents open from being called until it's released.

Final relevant code:

```
'Declare API
Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "User32" _
(ByVal vKey As Integer) As Integer
Const SHIFT_KEY = 16

Function ShiftPressed() As Boolean
'Returns True if shift key is pressed
    ShiftPressed = GetKeyState(SHIFT_KEY) < 0
End Function

...

    Do Until strFilename = ""
        Do While ShiftPressed()
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=myPath & "\" & strFilename, UpdateLinks:=False)
        Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)
        wsSrc.Copy after:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)
        wbSrc.Close False
        strFilename = Dir()
    Loop
```

Comment: I think this is verbatim what I am looking for to fix a nagging issue.  Thanks!